# Generate random int value from 3 to 6

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible in Microsoft SQL Server generate random int value from Min to Max (3-9 example, 15-99 e.t.c)

I know, I can generate from 0 to Max, but how to increase Min border?

This query generate random value from 1 to 6. Need to change it from 3 to 6.

```
SELECT table_name, 1.0 + floor(6 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) magic_number 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

**Added 5 sec later**:

```
SELECT table_name, 3.0 + floor(4 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) magic_number 
FROM information_schema.tables
```

Comment: The answer you have there only works if you have admin type permissions on the table. The way I got around this was by using the primary key on the field as the seed. The distribution wasn't brilliant, but it served the purpose.

Answer (score 267):

A helpful editor added the 'Select' before each statement but the point of this item is that it can generate unique keys for each row in a return, not just one item (For that I would us the Rand() function).
For example:
Select top 100 Rand(),* from tblExample

Would return the same random value for all 100 rows.

While:
Select top 100 ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10),* from tblexample

Would return a different random value between 0 and 9 on each row in the return.
So while the select makes it easier to copy and paste, you can copy the logic into a select statement if that is what is required.

This generates a random number between 0-9

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10)
```

1 through 6

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 6) + 1
```

3 through 6

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 4) + 3
```

Dynamic (Based on Eilert Hjelmeseths Comment - thanks to jiraiya for providing the visual presentation)

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (@max - @min + 1)) + @min
```

Updated based on comments:

- `NEWID` generates random string (for each row in return)
- `CHECKSUM` takes value of string and creates number
- modulus (`%`) divides by that number and returns the remainder (meaning max value is one less than the number you use)
- `ABS` changes negative results to positive
- then add one to the result to eliminate 0 results (to simulate a dice roll)

Comment: this helped me a ton! just remember if you're trying to generate random keys for bulk inserts this can cause duplicates and some statements will fail. but thank you!

Comment: What if I have to generate random number between 1 and 27? i.e. range greater then 9?

Comment: If I'm following the logic it seems this tweak will accurately let you dynamically set the range easily. `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (@max - @min + 1)) + @min` . A few tests on my part yielded good results. If it's indeed accurate I think this answer could be improved slightly by including it.

Comment: Your previous answer was correct: ```ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (@max - @min + 1)) + @min```. ```+1``` ensured that the max value was included in the range.  ```-1``` will in fact reduce the range of values by two. The mod operation is giving us the number to add to the min. But the max mod result is always 1 less than the mod parameter value. Hence for a range 3 - 6 (including min/max) one would need the following: ```ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (6 - 3 + 1)) + 3``` this gives a range [3,4,5,6]. ```ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % (6 - 3 - 1)) + 3``` will result in a range of nums [3,4].

Answer (score 14):

I see you have added an answer to your question in SQL Server 2008 you can also do

```
SELECT 3 + CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) % 4 /*Random number between 3 and 6*/ 
FROM ...
```

A couple of disadvantages of this method are

1. This is slower than the `NEWID()` method
2. Even though it is evaluated once per row the query optimiser does not realise this which [can lead to odd results](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/654809/crypt-gen-random-erroneously-treated-as-constant).

but just thought I'd add it as another option.

Comment: @FSou1 - Yes. I think `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` is really intended for situations where you need a more cryptographically secure pseudo random number.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
DECLARE @maxval TINYINT, @minval TINYINT
select @maxval=24,@minval=5

SELECT CAST(((@maxval + 1) - @minval) *
    RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + @minval AS TINYINT)
```

And that was taken directly from [this link](http://nathanielengelsen.com/2009/09/t-sql-random-number-generator-with-newid/), I don't really know how to give proper credit for this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Simply:

```
DECLARE @MIN INT=3; --We define minimum value, it can be generated.
DECLARE @MAX INT=6; --We define maximum value, it can be generated.

SELECT @MIN+FLOOR((@MAX-@MIN+1)*RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID()))); --And then this T-SQL snippet generates an integer between minimum and maximum integer values.
```

You can change and edit this code for your needs.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the simple and single line of code

For this use the SQL Inbuild **RAND()** function.

Here is the formula to generate random number between two number (RETURN INT Range)

Here a is your First Number (Min) and b is the Second Number (Max) in Range

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(b-a)+a)
```

Note: You can use CAST or CONVERT function as well to get INT range number.

( CAST(RAND()*(25-10)+10 AS INT) )

Example:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10)+10);
```

Here is the formula to generate random number between two number (RETURN DECIMAL Range)

```
SELECT RAND()*(b-a)+a;
```

Example:

```
SELECT RAND()*(25-10)+10;
```

More details check this: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/rand.php

Comment: Note, as mentioned in the linked article this will not actually generate values = Max.  To do this for example for  values  >= 10 and <= 25 you would need SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(25-10+1))+10

Answer (score 5):

Nice and simple, from Pinal Dave's site:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/

```
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT
SET @Lower = 3 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 7 ---- One more than the highest random number
SELECT @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random
```

(I did make a slight change to the @Upper- to include the upper number, added 1.)

Comment: I saw this example in another posting. It does not provide a random distribution. E.g., Lower is 1 and Upper is 11 so I want random numbers from 1 to 10. The 1 and the 10 get half the occurences as 2-8. Go and test it out.

Answer (score 2):

In general:

```
select rand()*(@upper-@lower)+@lower;
```

For your question:

```
select rand()*(6-3)+3;
```

**<=>**

```
select rand()*3+3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ROUND((6 - 3 * RAND()), 0)
```

Comment: The chance of getting one number over the other is not equally spread. Check the output of this:
`SELECT ROUND((6 - 3 * 0.16), 0)
SELECT ROUND((6 - 3 * 0.17), 0)
SELECT ROUND((6 - 3 * 0.5), 0)
SELECT ROUND((6 - 3 * 0.51), 0)
SELECT ROUND((6 - 3 * 0.83), 0)
SELECT ROUND((6 - 3 * 0.84), 0)`

Shows that 16% change for 6, ~34% it is 5, ~34% it is 4 and ~16% it is 3.

Comment: truncating is superior to rounding

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % (6 - 3+ 1) + 3 AS magic_number;
```

This is how you can generate random values on microsoft sql.

Comment: The general formula using this method is already given in the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Lamak's** answer as a function:

```
-- Create RANDBETWEEN function
-- Usage: SELECT dbo.RANDBETWEEN(0,9,RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())))
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RANDBETWEEN(@minval TINYINT, @maxval TINYINT, @random NUMERIC(18,10))
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT CAST(((@maxval + 1) - @minval) * @random + @minval AS TINYINT))
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @min INT = 3;
DECLARE @max INT = 6;
SELECT @min + ROUND(RAND() * (@max - @min), 0);
```

Step by step

```
DECLARE @min INT = 3;
DECLARE @max INT = 6;

DECLARE @rand DECIMAL(19,4) = RAND();
DECLARE @difference INT = @max - @min;
DECLARE @chunk INT = ROUND(@rand * @difference, 0);
DECLARE @result INT = @min + @chunk; 
SELECT @result;
```

Note that a user-defined function thus not allow the use of RAND(). A workaround for this (source: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/11/20/sql-server-using-rand-in-user-defined-functions-udf/) is to create a view first.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_RandomSeed]
AS
SELECT        RAND() AS seed
```

and then create the random function

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_RandomNumberBetween
(
    @min INT,
    @max INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @min + ROUND((SELECT TOP 1 seed FROM vw_RandomSeed) * (@max - @min), 0);
END
```