# How can I change the value of a primary key of a table to be a random number?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
    [WordId]        INT            NOT NULL,
    [Name]          VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [StatusId]      INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NULL,
    [Syllables]     VARCHAR (20)   NULL,
    [Ascii]         AS             (ascii([Name])) PERSISTED,
    [CategoryId]    INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [GroupId]       INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [LessonId]      INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy]     INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate]   DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy]    INT            DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate]  DATETIME       DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [Version]       ROWVERSION     NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WordId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_WordLesson] FOREIGN KEY ([LessonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Lesson] ([LessonId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_WordWordCategory] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[WordCategory] ([WordCategoryId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_WordWordGroup] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[WordGroup] ([WordGroupId])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Word_Category_IX]
    ON [dbo].[Word]([CategoryId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Word_Group_IX]
    ON [dbo].[Word]([GroupId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Word_Lesson_IX]
    ON [dbo].[Word]([LessonId] ASC);
```

How can I change the value of WordId to be a random number that is between 1 and the maximum value of the INT column?

Note that I understand there's a possibility of the random number being used twice but it's test data so I am not too concerned about that.

Comment: But why would you want to do that? What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a random number? it's the PK so you want to make sure that you're not creating duplicates. This is exactly the use for a identity column. Also, you talk about the maximum value of the INT column, which INT column?

Comment: Shouldn't primary key be unique by definition (even in test data)?

Comment: Do you want to "change" the primary key to a random number? Or do you want it to be a random number when the row is inserted?

Comment: @lopushen Yes, the primary key(s) have to be unique. He can have duplicates in `WorldId` only if he makes a compound primary key such as `(WorldId, SomeOtherColumn)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random int value from 3 to 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878287/generate-random-int-value-from-3-to-6)

Comment: Agreed with everyone that primary keys should be unique but would like to do this for test data purposes. As the max value would be the max of int I think with the 100 rows of test data I have there should be almost no chance of a duplicate. Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaJ check my answer to see the calculation using rand() that should do this for you.

Comment: @RichBenner - Thanks but it's not that I want to find out how to do it with rand().  I really need to know how to change each row. Can I do this with just an update for every row or would I need a cursor or something like that ?

Comment: sure, UPDATE TableName SET FieldName = ROUND(RAND()*FieldName),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a different approach to this than the route you are currently going down.

Just use an identity column, it's inbuilt and because this field is the Primary Key you need to ensure you don't get duplicates. The code would look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Word] (
[WordId]        INT            IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
```

It will give you a value starting with 1 that increments by 1 each time a new row of data is entered.

Also, looking at your code, you've got the field `StatusId` as nullable but with a default value, are you sure that you don't want this as a `NOT NULL` field?

For information, you can use this calculation to get a random number less than a given int value;

```
DECLARE @RandomInt int; SET @RandomInt = 42

SELECT
@RandomInt Number
,ROUND(RAND()*@RandomInt,0) RandomLessThanInt
```

You'll get an answer like this;

```
Number  RandomLessThanInt
42      15
```

It will obviously change every time it's run. You'd have to ensure that the number didn't already exist otherwise you will be attempting to violate the PK constraint and the insert will fail.

If you already have the table populated with data then you could do this

```
UPDATE TableName
SET FieldName = ROUND(RAND()*FieldName,0)
```

Comment: Thanks Rich,  but I moved away from using IDENTITY as I need this to be a random number for testing. It was using IDENTITY yesterday.  Just not sure how to change to random today.

Comment: @SamanthaJ i've just updated the answer to include the update statement you could run on your table. Might take a couple of attempts depending upon whether you get conflicting values.